# Incorrect validating Object when using Vee-Vallidate 4.11.7, Yup 4.11.8, Vue 3 and PrimeVue 3.30.2

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate, primevue

I am having an issue of getting a simple validation correct using Vee-Validation, Yup, PrimeVue and Vue 3.

My goal is to use a object to validate my entire form instead of using multiple useFields for single fields.
I have tried multiple solutions from the documentation, different stack overflow questions and chatgpt. Here's my current code which feels like should be on the correct path:

```
const formData = reactive({
    username: '',
    email: '',
});

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  username: yup.string().required('Username is required'),
  email: yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Email is required'),
});

const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  initialValues: formData.value,
  validationSchema,
});

const submitForm = handleSubmit(async (values) => {
  console.log('Form submitted with values:', values);
});
```

Here's the form:

```
 <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
   <div class="p-fluid formgrid grid">
    {{ errors }}
    <br>
    <hr />
      <div class="field col-12">
         <label for="username">Username</label>
         <InputText id="username" placeholder="Enter username" type="text" 
             v-bind="formData.username" :class="{ 'p-invalid': errors.username }" />
         <div class="text-red-500">{{ errors.username }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="field col-12">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <InputText id="email" placeholder="Enter email" type="text" 
           v-bind="formData.email" :class="{ 'p-invalid': errors.email }" />
      <div class="text-red-500">{{ errors.email }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <Button v-if="mode == 'create'" class="mr-1" label="Create" type="submit" />
    <Button v-if="mode == 'edit'" class="mr-1" label="Save Changes" type="submit" />
    <router-link to="/users">
      <Button class="secondary" label="Discard" />
    </router-link>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a screenshot, when the page load, the form fields are aleady invalid and it also never changes to valid when I enter the fields.[image]

Note all my code is in javascript.

Comment: I can help, can you share a codesandbox link for this setup?

Comment: @rachitiitr here you go: ```https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-dream-m2yf7y```

Comment: can you check the link? I dont think it renders the expected html right now.

Comment: the styling is off but the code is exactly what it is expected, 2 fields, validation added, and a submit buton.

Comment: @rachitiitr styling has been fixed. please have a look? thahnks